# How do I use the same method in both Controllers and Cells in cakephp 3.7?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have an utility method in my AppController, and I need to use that method inside a [Cell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) (backend).

Is there a standard way to use the same method in both places? I don't want to duplicate code.

Comment: Is it a static method? If not, could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard convention for sharing functions between Cell's and Controllers, it *could* be a sign of bad separation of concerns (but not necessarily!). I'd generally first make sure that this function is actually a "utility" and not better implemented some other way in general...

**That all said, there's probably a few ways to do shared functions:**

### Option A - Create A Utility Class

Cake itself places it's utility classes in `src/Utility`, for example the [Hash class](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html). It doesn't explicitly list using this directory structure yourself in the docs for your own Utilities, but I'd assume it's where they'd suggest if they did.

Stick the method in the Utility static class:

```
namespace App\Utility;

class Gravitar {
    public static function getUrl($username){
        // the function
    }
}
```

And then reference it with that namespace in each place, for example in the Controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Utility\Gravitar;

class PeopleController {

    public function view(){
        // Normal view etc.

        // Call by 
        Gravitar::getUrl($username );
    }
}
```

### Option B - Create A Trait

Stick the function in a trait. I would ONLY do this if you can't make the function static (and it might be a bad sign if you can't, it's probably not a true "utility").

There's no conventional place to put a shared trait. You could potentially place it in with other Controller Traits in `src/Controller/Traits`, reference it from there in a Cell:

```
namespace App\View\Cell;

use App\Controller\Traits\GravitarTrait;

class PeopleCell {

    use GravitarTrait;

    public function display(){
        // Normal cell display function.

        // Call by direct reference
        $this->getUrl($username);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also add the Trait version, while technically possible, feels like smelly code to me, shared between Cells and Controllers... If this function isn't spiritually something like Cake's own Hash function, it's not a Utility, there might be a better way to structure what you're doing in general.

Comment: I'm using version 3.7 and did not find a Utility folder, so I imagine I have to create it. Anyway your 1st option (A) seems to me a clean way !  And yes it is a utility function that can definitly be in a static method (  some custom staff I do on text ), it does not depend on anything else : you give it a param and it gives you the result .

Comment: You have to create it yeah, should have made that clearer :)