# Render view from another controller inside my view

Tags: cakephp

I don't know if this is possible, and i feel like its something i should not do, but i need it, so lets say:

I have a controller "A", this controller has a function that do some calculations and then there is the view that will render a div with some fields inside of it.

ok that is working, i can't touch that.

but now i have also the controller "B", this controller also has a function and a view, this view shows somethings and i need to show what is in the first case inside a div here (among the divs that are already present).

ps: the function on controller "A" needs two parameters.

There are some parts in this project that people used iframe and then .load() to show what is in A inside the iframe in another view, but i want to know if i can do this with cakephp itself using div.

cake version 2.4.9

Answer (score 0):

Controllers aren't meant to call functions in other Controllers in Cake, but Cake has a few features to let you share functions between Views.

From what you imply you are doing here, likely you could stick the function into a [View Cell](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/cells.html):

```
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\View\Cell;

class MyCell extends Cell
{ 
    // Pass whatever data you need to, to the Cell
    public function display($var1, $var2) 
    {
        // Your calculations previously done in Controller A, do here instead, Ex.
        $this->set('unread_count, $var1 - $var2);
    }
}
```

Then put whatever div contents in the Cell template:

```
<!-- templates/cell/MyCell/display.php -->
<div class="notification-icon">
    You have <?= $unread_count ?> unread messages.
</div>
```

Then plop the output into both Controller A & B's views, ex.:

```
<!-- In Controller A's & B's template, render where needed, passing the data needed: -->
<?= $this->cell('MyCell', [$var1, $var2]); ?>
```

This is only one option - depending on what exactly you're doing in that Controller, you could maybe stick the shared function into a Table, as a [Custom Finder](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data). You could stick the shared function in a plain old [PHP Trait or Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929574/2403513).

Comment: i think i get what you said, but i'm not alowed to change the code that is already done on controller "A" and its view. My thought was something like putting a $this->render("ControllerA", "ActionA") in viewB.ctp that would print what is printed in the viewA inside the viewB. So this is not possible? right? if not i'm forced to use the iframe aproach then...